# Plyr/data.table subsetting

Tags: r, data.table, subset, plyr

I've got data that is arrayed in a way that has day/month/year in separate columns (which is useful for how I need to subset the data).  Each column besides the D/M/Y are columns of values.  In my real data, these are counties in the U.S.

I need to sum different ranges of dates that vary by different day, month and year combinations.  Given that each column is a county, the ddply/data.table/apply functions seem to be the most appropriate to solve the problem.  However, I cannot figure out how to subset my data.

Here is a trivial example:

```
set.seed(1234)

data <- data.frame(day=rep(seq(1,5),9), month= rep(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(11,5)),3), 
                   year=c(rep(1999,15),rep(2000,15),rep(2001,15)), Abel = round(runif(n=45, 0, 5),2) ,
                   Bertha=round(runif(n=45, 0, 5),2),  Charlie= round(runif(n=45,0, 5),2))

dt <- data.table(data)
keycols <- c("day", "month", "year")
setkeyv(dt, keycols) #not sure if this is necessary
```

Originally, I was thinking of using the ddply() command with the summarize option but have seen other instances where people have recommended using the data.table framework.  However, I cannot figure out a way to subset the data in such a way that would get it to match results as follows:

```
sum(data$Abel[which(data$year==1999 & data$month==2 & data$day >=1 & data$day <4)]) #4.41
sum(data$Bertha[which(data$year==1999 & data$month==2 & data$day >=1 & data$day <4)]) #5.51
sum(data$Charlie[which(data$year==1999 & data$month==2 & data$day >=1 & data$day <4)]) #4.19
```

While this example might seem easy, I have to calculate 10-day averages of climate data for hundreds of counties over decades, so getting the ddply/data.table framework to work would really help!

I have tried both data.table and ddply, but both with errors:

```
dt[i=list(year==1999, month==2, day >=1, day<3), sum]
#Error in `[.data.table`(dt, i = list(year == 1999, month == 2, day >=  : 
#  typeof x.day (integer) != typeof i.day (logical)
```

I realize that this means that I'm doing something wrong with setting up the data.table, but I haven't used it before and have looked through several help files and can't figure out the subset issues.

For ddply, I get a different error when I just try to use one singular column to try and get it to work:

```
ddply(data, .(year, month, day, Abel), summarize, sum.val = sum )
#Error in vector(type, length) : 
#  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'builtin'.
```

Any guidance on solving this type of problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want to sum over the grouping variables?

Comment: The results from `sum` expessions is wrong isn't?

Comment: @PauloCardoso : Each column represents precipitation data for that county, so I'd like to sum that for different ranges of day/month/year that will change.  Does that make sense? Or do I need to clarify?

Comment: I don't think the `sum` statements are wrong.  I just double checked and just confirmed them.

Comment: ummm sure? `data$Abel[data$year==1999 & data$month==2 & data$day >=1 & data$day <4]` = `[1] 3.94 2.28 2.24`

Comment: Did you set.seed(1234)?  I continue to get these values for it: ` data$Abel[data$year==1999 & data$month==2 & data$day >=1 & data$day <4] = [1] 3.20 0.05 1.16`

Comment: Sorry. I adjusted my code. I completely missed the set.seed line. It is working as the example you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are close with `data.table`, you just need to modify how you are using the `i` statement.

```
dt[year==1999 & month==2 & between(day,0,2), lapply(.SD,sum), .SDcols=4:6]

   Abel Bertha Charlie
1: 3.25   1.92    4.06
```

You might also be interested in using the `ISOdate` function to make it a bit easier to work with your data.

```
dt[ , Date := ISOdate(year, month, day)]
```

From reading some of the comments in the other answer, it seems like this might be more of a rolling calc question. This https://github.com/mgahan/boRingTrees R package might of some help of you need running sums or averages or whatever.

Comment: This works.  I appreciate the help with figuring out the `i' statement.  I'll check out the other packages as well!

Comment: You should be able to get 10 day (rolling) averages with `rollmean` in the package `zoo`. With your data above, I think it would look something like `library(zoo); dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x){rollmean(x,k=10)}),.SDcols=-c(1:3)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to start

```
library(reshape2)
datam <- melt(data, id.vars = c('day', 'month', 'year'),
              variable.name = "name")
library(dplyr)
datam %>%
  filter(year==1999, month==2, day %in% 1:3) %>%
  group_by(year, month, name) %>%
  summarise(summed = sum(value))


Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: year, month

  year month    name summed
1 1999     2    Abel   4.41
2 1999     2  Bertha   5.51
3 1999     2 Charlie   4.19
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this code more, but I'm trying to get something to the effect that it would summarize at the end to:  `Abel 4.41` as this is the summed value for Abel for (d/m/y) 1/2/1999: (3.2) 2/2/1999: (0.05) and 3/2/1999: (1.16)